# Android Canvas Paint Arc Border

Tags: android, canvas, paint

I am drawing an arc with a border by painting two arcs, one over the other the first being slightly larger.

The issue is with "slightly larger" this can end up with the border not always being even all the way round.

[image: Example]

Both the arcs I am drawing have the same radius, I simply make it larger by adding a degree to the start and  two degrees to the end (necessary to ensure the borders on either end of the arc are equal) and increasing the stroke width.

In the supplied picture the thicker border edge is the smallest I can possibly make it while it is still visible. (-1 degree off the inner arc)

I have considered drawing the arc outline with four separate calls two straight lines for either end and two arcs. This seems quite inefficient for what I want to achieve.

I am wondering if anyone has any suggestions about how else I could draw a border thats even, minimizing the number of draw/canvas rotation calls if possible.

Relevant code sample for current solution:

```
Paint mOutlinePaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
Paint mFillPaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);

mFillPaint.setStyle(Style.STROKE);
mFillPaint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.SRC));
mFillPaint.setColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
mFillPaint.setStrokeWidth(mValueWidth);

mOutlinePaint.setStyle(Style.STROKE);
mOutlinePaint.setStrokeWidth(mBorderWidth);
mOutlinePaint.setColor(Color.WHITE);

mRect.set(mHalfXSubRadius, mHalfYSubRadius, mHalfXAddRadius, mHalfYAddRadius);
canvas.drawArc(mRect, ARC_START-1, MAX_ARC+2, false, mOutlinePaint);
canvas.drawArc(mRect, ARC_START, MAX_ARC, false, mFillPaint);
```

Answer (score 0):

U shouldnt make your arc bigger, instead try to draw the same sized arc (in white), X pixel right,down,up,left,corners as well (total of 8 drawings).

where X is the border size u want.

after that draw the main arc (in gray) in the middle.

psuedo code:

```
paint=white;
drawArc(x,y+2);
drawArc(x,y-2);
drawArc(x+2,y+2);
drawArc(x+2,y-2);
drawArc(x-2,y+2);
drawArc(x-2,y+2);
drawArc(x+2,y);
drawArc(x-2,y);

paint=gray;
drawArc(x,y);
```